# Typical performance in Slick (ver. 3.1.1)

Tags: performance, slick, slick-3.0

I have following SQL query:

```
select `sr_roleName`, `sr_id` from `db_security_role` where `sr_roleName` = 'admin'
```

It's generated from following Slick code:

```
RoleTable.filter(_.name === roleName).result.head
```

So - it seems pretty straightforward (actually the simplest thing you may have, right?). Now let's look at the following results (logs below):

```
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark - ------------------- Phase: Time ---------
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -       assignUniqueSymbols:    0.257579 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -                inferTypes:    0.774230 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -              expandTables:   18.949290 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -           forceOuterBinds:    3.438698 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -         removeMappedTypes:    2.760705 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -                expandSums:    0.702326 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -         emulateOuterJoins:    1.025963 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -             expandRecords:    1.022323 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -        flattenProjections:   10.691557 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -              rewriteJoins:    0.790561 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -             verifySymbols:    4.421257 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -             relabelUnions:    1.511849 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -          createAggregates:    0.612787 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -           resolveZipJoins:    0.723972 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -          pruneProjections:    4.261886 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -           rewriteDistinct:    2.408857 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -    createResultSetMapping:    2.745822 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -            hoistClientOps:    7.755399 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -         reorderOperations:    1.650360 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -     mergeToComprehensions:   27.408578 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -            optimizeScalar:    1.784032 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -          removeFieldNames:   13.811206 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -                   codeGen:   20.328294 ms
[debug] s.c.QueryCompilerBenchmark -                     TOTAL:  129.837531 ms
[debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: select `sr_roleName`, `sr_id` from `db_security_role` where `sr_roleName` = 'admin'
[debug] s.j.J.benchmark - Execution of prepared statement took 425µs
```

As you can see actual query execution costs (takes time) about 425µs. Possible - it's executed on the local machine / local database. What however is extremely strange for me is this: whole query preparation time altogether costs 129.837531 ms (which is 300x the time of actual query execution).

So basically my question is:

- is this a typical performance characteristic of Slick?
- is there anything obvious that I may be doing wrong ?

thanks

Comment: You're probably just measuring wrong. For a first run of the query compiler this looks completely normal. After proper JIT warm-up I would expect a single-digit ms compile time on my 2012 MacBookPro. Look at [CompilerBenchmark](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/test/scala/slick/benchmark/CompilerBenchmark.scala). Averaged over 53 queries of low to medium complexity, I get 183 ms for the first run and only 14 ms after a few dozen runs.

Comment: Yes, warmup might be the case actually. It make sense - these numbers come from running single unit test.

Comment: @szeiger I think your comment should be the actual answer. Measurement was incorrect - I tested only single test. It's exactly as you described. 
If you would consider creating the actual answer I would happily mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the correct answer is in this comment by @szeiger: [Typical performance in Slick (ver. 3.1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725886/typical-performance-in-slick-ver-3-1-1#comment66788554_39725886)

Large query preparation times are simply caused by JVM not being warmed up. After executing various queries multiple times, next ones are prepared much faster. It's also worth to remember query compilation pointed by @Roman (although this is not really what the question in its essence is all about).

This quote from @szeiger in mentioned comment basically is the best answer for this question:

> Averaged over 53 queries of low to medium complexity, I get 183 ms for the first run and only 14 ms after a few dozen runs

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be reasonable. Each time a parameterized query is executed, slick will need to recompile it. This can be avoided by pre-compiling such queries. For example:

```
def findByRoleName(roleName: Rep[String]) = RoleTable.filter(_.name === roleName)

val findByRoleNameCompiled = Compiled(findByRoleName _)

val result = findByRoleNameCompiled("myRole").result.head
```

Now the query will be compiled only once and you should notice an improved performance. This also works for inserting, updating and deleting. For details see [Compiled Queries](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html#compiled-queries) in the docs.

Comment: Ok - I get idea of precompiled query. No problem here - but is it really possible (typical?) that query compilation takes so much time (even with such a simple query)?

Comment: Judging from the code you showed, I can't see anything wrong with it. But going through the benchmark results again, compilation takes indeed a bit long. However, those numbers can be totally random as we don't know how the measurement was done. I'd suggest to gather some more benchmark results and see if it still takes that long. See https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/test/scala/slick/benchmark/CompilerBenchmark.scala for an example how to get useful numbers.